# Python Interpreter can be implemented in Python, but which interpreter will interpret the Interpreter itself?

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

1 I found a Python Interpreter implemented in Python. I am confused whether I need to install other interpreter to interpret the Interpreter itself?
If so, why need we bother to write interpreter in the language which it will interpret? If not, how do I run this interpreter?

2 I am also not very clear about the compiler which is implemented in the language which it will compile. Does the interpreter and compiler have the same reason behind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need some other interpreter to run it. In the case of a compiler, you could compile it once with a different compiler, and then use that executable code to compile the source code again. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Answer (score 0):

If we write a program which can interpret simple math expression such as `1 + 2 * 3`. The program is written in C.

```
// bash
> ./calculate "1 + 2 * 3"
> 7
```

So a C language program can interpret a simple math language.

Obviously, we can choose Ruby or Python instead of C to write this program. Finally, a Ruby or Python language program can interpret a math language.

Let's make the program interpret a more complex language, such as Python. Then we got it. A Python language program interpret a Python language.

So, any language can interpret any language.

Compiler compile source code to machine code, so it can run in CPU directly, Interpreter interpret source code to byte code, so it can run in a virtual machine. The only difference is the CPU existed already but virtual machine need to be compiled first.

*sorry for my poor english.*

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this technique (called bootstrapping, as another user correctly answered), can be to use different techniques of compiler optimizations and works (roughly) as follows:

Suppose you have a working Compiler Y, which compiles a Language X to, say, Assembly Language. Then this Compiler is everything you need to translate a program written in Language X to a form that is understandable and executable (after linking etc.) on your machine.

Now, you think this compiler is well-written in its core aspects, but not so good written in other aspects (for example: it is very slow in evaluating a long case-statement).

What you do is: you rewrite the complete language X by using only a subset (well-implemented with compiler Y) of language X and optimize the evaluation of mentioned long case-statements (example).

Now you have a compiler Z, which evaluates a program of language X to a program which consists only of core-statements of language X. With compiler Y you can now translate it to Assembly Language.

Generally: At some point in a long row of compilers there should be one compiler, which actually generates valid machine instructions or you won't be able to execute your nice program (sounds trivial, but good to keep in mind).

EDIT @merito: a compiler translates a program from a source language to a target language, which can be binary code, but doesn't have to. Your distinction between interpreter and compiler seems wrong to me.